# Python function arguments and documentation confusion

Tags: python

Here is a string in python:

```
a = "asdf as df adsf as df asdf asd f"
```

Lets say that I want to replace all " " with "||", so I do:

```
>>> a.replace(" ", "||")
'asdf||as||df||adsf||as||df||asdf||asd||f'
```

My confusion is info from [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) as below:

```
 string.replace(s, old, new[, maxreplace])
    Return a copy of string s with all occurrences...
```

I can "omit" `s`, but based on the documentation I need `s`; however, I only provide `old`, and `new`. I noticed that it's like this with a lot of the python documentation; what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of a method is a reference to the object (usually called `self`) being modified and is *implicitly passed* when you use the `object.method(...)` notation. So this:

```
a = "asdf as df adsf as df asdf asd f"
print a.replace(" ", "||")
```

is equivalent to this:

```
a = "asdf as df adsf as df asdf asd f"
print str.replace(a, " ", "||")
```

`str` being the class of the `a` object. It's just syntactical sugar.

Answer (score 5):

You are mixing up `str` object methods with the `string` module functions.

The documentation you are referring to is the [`string` module documentation.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) Indeed, there is a function in the string module called `replace` which takes 3 (or optionally, 4) arguments:

```
In [9]: string
Out[9]: <module 'string' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/string.pyc'>

In [11]: string.replace(a, ' ', '||')
Out[11]: 'asdf||as||df||adsf||as||df||asdf||asd||f'
```

`a` is a `str` object -- (`str` is a type,  `string` is a module):

```
In [15]: type(a)
Out[15]: str
```

And `str` objects have a `replace` method. The documentation for the `str` methods is [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

Comment: I would add that the `string` module should not be used since most of its functionalities have been merged with the `str` string class, +1

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: There are some string functions which [are deprecated](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#deprecated-string-functions), like `string.atof`, but the whole module is not deprecated. The functions can be useful when you need the function, not the method bound to a particular `str`, and the constants are useful too.

Comment: Yeah, I reworded the comment shortly after with _should not be used_. What I said is in the first paragraph of the `string` module docs. As of "free functions", you could just use `str.upper` and the like (e.g. `map(str.upper, ["a", "b"])`).

Answer (score 1):

When you call a method of an object, the object is supplied automatically as the first parameter.  Generally within the method this is referred to as `self`.

So you can call the function passing in the object:

```
string.replace(s, old, new)
```

or you can call the method of the object:

```
s.replace(old, new)
```

Both are functionally identical.

Comment: It's `str`, not `string`.